# PYTHON não consigo identificar o erro no código

Tags: python

```
import pyautogui

life50 = pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(663, 306, (25, 195, 25))

if: life50 
    pyautogui.press('f1')
else: 
    pyautogui.screenshot('C:/Users/ANDRE/Desktop/Imagens')
```

Estou aprendendo a programar em python e o código acima não está funcionando e eu não consigo identificar o erro, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Leia [Como debugar programas pequenos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7785/como-debugar-programas-pequenos)

Comment: Altere de `if: life50` para `if life50:`

Answer (score 1):

Você utilizou os `:` no lugar errado. Faça a alteração que o Paulo Marques sugeriu, troque

```
if: life50
```

para

```
if life50:
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo :)